# Combine video and audio with moviepy in mobile app

Tags: python, ffmpeg, kivy, moviepy

```
import moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools as mvp
def Merge(self,title:str):  # Kombiniert die Video und die Audiodatei
    self.percent.text = "Verarbeiten..."
    os.rename(f"{self.outpath}/{title}.mp4", f"{self.outpath}/tmp_video.mp4")
    os.rename(f"{self.outpath}/{title}.mp3", f"{self.outpath}/tmp_video.mp3")
    mvp.ffmpeg_merge_video_audio( f"{self.outpath}/tmp_video.mp4",  f"{self.outpath}/tmp_video.mp3",
                                 f"{self.outpath}/{title}.mp4")
    os.remove(f"{self.outpath}/tmp_video.mp4")
    os.remove(f"{self.outpath}/tmp_video.mp3")
```

I want to combine video and audio with moviepy in a kivy app on Android.I tried to build the app with the following requirements: python3,kivy,Pillow,typing_extensions,requests,urllib3,android,moviepy,imageio,Decorator,tqdm,numpy,imageio_ffmpeg,ffmpeg,proglog

The app crashes and when i set the environmental variable with

```
import os
os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
```

it does build the app but crashes when i try it out.
Is there something that I am missing or is it not possible to build this type of app?

Comment: did you check if `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` really exists? Maybe you should use `try/except` to catch error, and `logging` to write this error in file - to see this later (after crash)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.generators import Sine

# Create a sample audio file (replace this with your actual audio file)
audio = Sine(440).to_audio_segment(duration=5000)  # 5 seconds of a 440 Hz sine wave

# Load a video file (replace this with your actual video file)
video = VideoFileClip("path/to/your/video.mp4")

# Combine audio and video
video = video.set_audio(audio)

# Export the merged video
video.write_videofile("output_video.mp4", codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```